# join criteria with group

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

How do I write a criteria for following SQL

```
SELECT
m.match_type, 
count(m.match_type)
cat.description, 
loc.oid

FROM
USER_MATCH m, 
RECORD rec, 
CATEGORY cat, 
LOCATION loc

WHERE
m.record_oid = rec.oid and 
rec.category_oid = cat.oid and 
rec.location_oid = loc.oid
group by m.match_type, cat.description, loc.oid
```

I have attempt it as following but I'm getting 
subquery expressions not allowed here error.

```
Criteria criteria = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Match.Class);
criteria.createAlias("record", "record");
criteria.createAlias("category", "category");

ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();        
projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("record.categoryId"));  
projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("record.locationId")); 
criteria.setProjection(projList);
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
Criteria criteria = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Match.Class);
criteria.createAlias("record", "record");
criteria.createAlias("category", "category");
criteria.createAlias("location", "location");

ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();  
projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("match_type"));      
projList.add(Projections.count("match_type");
projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("record.categoryId"));  
projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("record.locationId")); 
criteria.setProjection(projList);
```

**Note** that you need not to include join condition in hibernate because this will automatically handeled by CreateALias.